# Error- Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory' in .net core 5 with npgsql

Tags: entity-framework-6, npgsql, asp.net-core-5.0

Trying to run a .Net Core 5 Web API project but when I am trying to connecting npgsql getting

> "provider name"

error .

I am using `connectionStrings` in `App.config` and `DbProviderFactories` in `machine.config` file.

trying to connect `npgsql` in `WebApiConfig` file

```
var connection = new pgsql.NpgsqlConnection(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("dbcontext"));
var db = new DbContext(connection, true);
db.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Getting this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctxhn.png)

Someone have an idea? how can I resolved this error in .Net core.

Answer (score 0):

machine.config is not supported on .NET Core (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/32307).

For managing connection strings with ASP.NET, see [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings) and/or [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro).